# Array fetch or default function

Tags: ruby, arrays

I need the following logic. If array contains `value`, return it else return some default value. So far, I've found this can be achieved by using `delete`:

```
array.delete(value) || default_value
```

But, obviously, it modifies the array. Is there a similar function like `fetch` with default which takes an element instead of an index?

PS. I know this can be rewritten as `array.include?(value) ? value : default_value`, the question is just for the sake of cleaner code.

Comment: I'm afraid you won't find any simpler code for this (the latter), which means you have to implement your own `fetch` which hides that complexity :-)
Alternative (if the default is `6`): `ary.find(lambda{6}){|x| x == 6}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** There's one way I can think of, but that's harder to read than the ternary:

```
 (array & [value]).first || default_value
```

You could monkey-patch that into `Array` if you are so inclined:

```
class Array
  def fetch_value(value, default)
    (self & [value]).first || default
  end
end

a = *1..3
a.fetch_value(4, "foo")
#=> "foo"
```

**Old answer, before I realized you want to use the value for the lookup, not the index:**

[Array#fetch](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-fetch) takes an optional second argument:

```
array.fetch(index, default)
```

Here's an example:

```
a = *1..3
a.fetch(4, "foo")
#=> "foo"
```

Comment: He doesn't want specify the `index`. He wants to know if an Array contains a value, then return that value otherwise return the default.